# Efficiently cluster Gaussian vectors

Tags: clustering, gaussian

Let $X^i,1\leq i\leq n$ iid Gaussian vectors of $\mathbb{R}^p$. I want to cluster the coordinates $1\leq j\leq p$ knowing the following facts:

- Each coordinate $X^i_j$ is centred and has variance $1$, $1\leq j\leq p$
- here are "unknown" classes $C_1,...,C_K$ on $\{1,...,n\}$ and $\epsilon_n\to 0,\delta> 0$ such that if $k,l$ are in the same class, $Cov(X^i_k,X^i_l)\geq 1-\epsilon_n$, and if they are in different classes the covariance is $\leq 1-\delta$.

Hence the goal is to retrieve the classes with maximal probability, in a small time when $n$ is large. Maybe it is more natural to view the data as $p$ vectors of size $n$, it is not clear to me.

I can think of many different ways to achieve my goal, but I expect from the literature that there is an efficient algorithm both from the point of view of the performance and of the computational cost, with theoretical guarantees. Does anyone knows an optimal algorithm here?